# Code freezes when creating a role without an error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem. I want to create roles automatically. The peculiarity is that the role looks like this `00101`.
The problem is that although `here1` is printed, the creation of the role is not done and the code "freezes" without any error message.

What could be the reason for this?`

```py
class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True

        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('!'), intents=intents)

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
        print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')
    
        activity = discord.Game(name="Tetris", type=1)
    
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)

bot = Bot()

async def createRole(guild, countries, citys):
    lst_1 = []
    lst_2 = []
    lst_code = []
    lst_combinded = []
    for i, country in enumerate(countries, 1):
        for j, city in enumerate(citys, 1):
            code = f"{i:03d}{j:02d}"
            print(code)
            lst_1.append(country)
            lst_2 .append(city)
            lst_code.append(code)
            lst_combinded.append(str(country.lower()+"_"+city.lower()))
            print(lst_combinded)

            role_object = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=code)
            #await role_object.delete()
            if(role_object is None):
                print("here1")
                await guild.create_role(name=str(code), colour=discord.Colour(0xffffff))
                print("here2")

...
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True, ban_members=True) 
@bot.command()
async def create(ctx):
    await createRole(ctx.guild, countries, citys)
```

Comment: Don't make API calls in `on_ready`

Comment: @stijndcl Thank you for pointing this out. Why not? 
However, the bot should do that as soon as it is started.

Comment: Making API calls in `on_ready` has a high chance of making Discord disconnect your bot, and `on_ready` can get triggered multiple times. If you want to run something on startup then you can make a task that runs only once.

Comment: Either way, where are you getting that `guild` instance from? Chances are very high it's not in the cache yet, so it's actually None. Are you sure the Guild instance is not None? It should give you an error but if it's None then your bot won't freeze - it'll just raise an exception and stop executing that function

Comment: Okay, thank you for the hint. `guild` is not empty :/. I will update my question

Comment: Which prints get executed and which don't?

Comment: `here1` and after that nothing.

Comment: How are you running your bot? Did you configure logging properly?

Comment: I changed my code. Now the code runs inside `@bot.command()` but still the same. Only the first print `here1` is printed.

Comment: Again, don't make API calls in `on_ready`. It's useless to call `change_presence` over there, just pass it to the `__init__` when you create your `Bot` instance.

Comment: And I meant how you're running your **bot**. As in, how are you starting it.

Comment: I am starting it with `python bot.py`

Comment: If I am starting the bot on a new server, everything run smoothly without any freeze

Comment: I meant code-wise, not how you're invoking the script..

Comment: I am confused. What do you mean? :/ I am running it locally

Comment: What part in your code starts the bot...?